# filter result to top 5 highest mark if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-filters

I am new to angularjs.
My objective is to filter records of students limitto:5 if the checkbox Top 5 Mark is checked.
If checkbox Top 5 Mark is unchecked, return all records that satisfy the other filters.

I also have other search box to filter the records. But that is out of the scope right now.

My filter code is like this for now

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    Top 5 Marks
  </label>
</div>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="item in students | filter:query | orderBy: orderName">

                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.mark}}</td>
                <td>{{item.grade}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: if my answer was useful for you? I'm open to any feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you can do it with the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <label>Top 5</label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="changeLimit(5)"/>
        <br/> <br/>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="student in students | orderBy: 'mark': true | limitTo: limitNumber">
                <span>{{student.name}}</span>
                <span>{{student.mark}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Your JS code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {      
    $scope.students = [
        { name: "Peter", mark: 10 },
        { name: "John", mark: 9 },
        { name: "Hevery", mark: 7 },
        { name: "Archy", mark: 10 },
        { name: "Michael", mark: 4 },
        { name: "Wats", mark: 4 },
        { name: "Richard", mark: 8 },
        { name: "Ivan", mark: 6 },
    ];

     $scope.limitNumber = $scope.students.length;
            $scope.changeLimit = function(limit){
        if($scope.checked){
           $scope.limitNumber = limit;
        } 
        else{
          $scope.limitNumber = $scope.students.length;      
        }
    };
};
```

I've attached [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7652/) example to the post.

Also I suggest to read about [**limitTo**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) and [**orderBy**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filters.